# Permissions tests issue with Docker volume mounting NFS share

Tags: python, linux, docker, file-permissions, nfs

I have an issue with the following python code

```py
import os
print("Can I write into the tv folder?",os.access("/tv", os.W_OK))
print("Does the /tv/test file exists?", os.access("/tv/test", os.R_OK))
with open("/tv/test", "w") as f:
    f.write("toto")
print("Does the /tv/test file exists now?", os.access("/tv/test", os.R_OK))
with open("/tv/test", "r") as f:
    print("Content of the /tv/test file:")
    print(f.read())
```

it prints out

```
Can I write into the tv folder? False
Does the /tv/test file exists? False
Does the /tv/test file exists now? True
Content of the /tv/test file;
toto
```

But according to the first call to `os.access`, I should not have been able to write the test file...

My problem is not the fact that it has been able to create the file, I want that. But the test should produce a relevant result. (a software that I use is malfunctioning because of this)

I'm running Python 3.8.10 in a docker container (Docker version 20.10.7) on a raspberry pi, and the tv folder is a remote nfs share mounted by docker.

```sh
root@7f0a44aad8a9:/> ls -la /tv
total 8
drwxrwxrwx 1 abc  abc   3826 Jul 27 14:18  .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root  4096 Jul 27 14:12  ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 abc  abc    988 May 13 07:30 DARK
... (a lot of other folders)
-rwxrwxrwx 1 abc  abc      4 Jul 27 14:18  test
```

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.4"

services:
  bazarr:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/bazarr
    container_name: bazarr
    volumes:
      - shows:/tv
    ports:
      - 6767:6767
    dns: 1.1.1.1
    restart: unless-stopped

volumes:
  shows:
    driver_opts:
      type: "nfs"
      o: "nfsvers=3,addr=xxx,soft,rw"
      device: ":xxx"
```

I know that `os.access` can give false positive, but false negative ?
Does anyone have already seen this ?
Is this to be expected ?

EDIT: the problem is not python specific

```sh
root@6c5dd99ee211:/> if [ -w /tv ]; then echo "WRITABLE"; else echo "NOT WRITABLE"; fi
NOT WRITABLE
```

But why?

Comment: Can you do `ls -la /tv`?

Comment: Have you verified that your problem is in fact with the *Python* code and not the underlying operation? For example, does ``test -w /tv`` succeed in the shell?

Comment: You are right, `test -w /tv` fails. But why ? since I do have the right to create files inside.

Answer (score 2):

This has much more to do with POSIX file systems (which includes *nix filesystems) than it does with Python.

> But according to the first call to os.access, I should not have been able to write the test file...

No, unfortunately this is false (but admittedly somewhat unintuitive).

In a POSIX file system, you may not have permission to write to a directory (which is what you checked), but this *does not* imply you cannot write to files within that directory. What it means is that you cannot write *new* files to said directory.

Example:

```
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ mkdir test_dir
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ touch test_dir/abc.txt
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ cat test_dir/abc.txt
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ chmod 777 test_dir/abc.txt
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ chmod 500 test_dir
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ touch test_dir/new_file.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test_dir/new_file.txt': Permission denied
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ echo "123" > test_dir/abc.txt
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ cat test_dir/abc.txt
123
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ ls -al test_dir/
total 12
dr-x------  2 mmessersmith mmessersmith 4096 Jul 27 09:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 mmessersmith mmessersmith 4096 Jul 27 09:31 ..
-rwxrwxrwx  1 mmessersmith mmessersmith    4 Jul 27 09:32 abc.txt
```

Note that I could not write a new file to the directory `test_dir`, but I can still write to `abc.txt` within `test_dir`. In your example above, you need to check `os.access("/tv/test", os.W_OK)`. In my REPL for the example above:

```
(base) mmessersmith@HP-ZBK-0425:~$ python
Python 3.8.3 (default, May 19 2020, 18:47:26)
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.access('test_dir', os.W_OK)
False
>>> os.access('test_dir/abc.txt', os.R_OK)
True
>>> os.access('test_dir/abc.txt', os.W_OK)
True
```

Lastly, observe that `os.access` is a simple wrapper around the linux/unix access: https://manpages.debian.org/buster/manpages-dev/access.2.en.html.

So no, it's not a false positive or false negative, it's just how the filesystem happens to work.

Comment: sorry, due to repetitive tests I made a mistake. I can create a new file in the directory tv and that's what's surprising. sorry for that

Comment: @pums974 in your example above, you're showing the file _already_ exists. e.g. you call `os.access("/tv/test", os.R_OK)` and it returned true. Secondly, `os.access` is relative to user who invokes. So if you invoke as yourself, but your docker daemon is running under root, you're bound to get different results.

Comment: Scratch that, seems like you just changed said call to return false....

Comment: yes, I made the mistake as I was writing the question and trying to make it as clear as possible. Again, I'm sorry.

Comment: Also seems like there's more than one mistake, b/c `/tv` has 777 perms. Please make sure to copy/paste _exactly_ what's going on in your situation....

Comment: @pums974 But then `os.access("/tv", os.W_OK)` would return `True`, not `False`. The example seems to be inconsistent with itself. If it's got 777 _anyone_ can write to it.